# When I start docker-compose in VS gives me an error on an API

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose, docker-container, .net-6.0

I have 2 API and one frontend Project, when I start docker-compose in VS gives me an error on an API (I restarted docker desktop app). If I run all the apps without docker, the apps worked perfectly.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   DT1001  Service 'authorapi' failed to build : Build failed
If the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop.   docker-compose  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets   399
```

I'm using VS2022 with a .net core app, .net6.0.

docker-compode.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  bookmemoriesweb:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}bookmemoriesweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Frontend\BookMemoriesWeb\Dockerfile

  authorapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}authorapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services\AuthorAPI\Dockerfile


  booksapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}booksapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services\BookAPI\Dockerfile
```

I created with VS Container Orchestrator Support...

Dockerfile of author API

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/AuthorAPI/AuthorAPI.csproj", "Services/AuthorAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/AuthorAPI/AuthorAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/AuthorAPI"
RUN dotnet build "AuthorAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AuthorAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AuthorAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: And `authorapi` docker file? And what if you try to build it separately?

Comment: I added the dockerfile on first post